# Will there be another Ubuntu 16.04 point release (16.04.7)?

Tags: 16.04

I don't think 16.04.6 was expected to happen so is there a chance 16.04.7 will happen before April 2021?

Comment: Only if it's beneficial for Canonical/Ubuntu purposes, ie. ESM customers usually.  The spinning & required testing of ISO/releases takes resources (paid & voluntary) so it's only utilized if there is benefit for company (Canonical) or community (if involved or during LTS life).  Don't forget flavors have already abandoned 16.04 (3 years support only for flavors), so the community still involved with 16.04 is now far smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is now a YES

Refer http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/416/builds

ie. there a QA-testing page for

> Xenial 16.04.7

Ubuntu 16.04.7 has now been released

> The Ubuntu team announces the release of Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (Long-Term Support) for its Desktop and Server products, and the Ubuntu Kylin flavor.
>
> Similar to the 16.04.6 point release, 16.04.7 is a security-targeted release for the purpose of providing updated installation media which protects new installations from the recently discovered GRUB 2 vulnerabilities (USN-4432-1). Detailed information about USN-4432-1 can be found here:
>
> https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4432-1

http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-16-04-7-lts-released/

https://ubuntu.com//blog/mitigating-boothole-theres-a-hole-in-the-boot-cve-2020-10713-and-related-vulnerabilities

Comment: I'm also involved with *Ubuntu News* and haven't seen notice in that capacity either, at least not yet.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.7 has been officially released - https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2020-August/000261.html   It was announced on IRC at the same time as 18.04.5, but a little later by the more official ML post.